# Error 13012 when calling Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync

Tags: office-js

Last night my Word Addin project was working fine, this morning when I call Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync() I get a response 13012 "An internal error has occurred."

This error code is not listed with the other getAccessTokenAsync, which only go up to 13010.  I have tried a variety of things, logging out of all accounts, different user, new project.  I do not see anything interesting in Fiddler.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've got the product team investigating. In the meantime, what platform are you using? Word Windows desktop? Word Online? Word on Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug that we think we've fixed. Please close all Office applications. Then reopen them and try the Word add-in again.

FYI: 13012 is brand new, which is why it is not documented. It is supposed to mean that getAccessTokenAsync is not supported on the current platform. For example, we don't yet support it on iPad. It was a bug that was causing you to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Some users in our company experience this issue too:

`13012 - Die API wird in dieser Plattform nicht unterstützt.`

It happens in an Outlook add-in which uses the `getAccessTokenAsync` function. The Office client version is 1808, Build 10730.20102 (on Windows 10). I have already tried reopening Outlook, clearing cache & cookies of the add-in (page) but without success. Somehow the problem occurs only for a few users but all users have the same client version, etc.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?